# Is it okay to cancel a T-SQL database backup script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I needed to run a backup of a very large database (which has a scheduled transaction log backup) but it was running too long and i killed the process (which took a long time to rollback) -- between then and my next backup, will the cancellation cause any data loss?

In case it doesn't seem clear, here's a rephrasing:

I killed a backup process - and I will start another one tomorrow - in any way, is the cancellation bad for the next backup?

Answer (score 1):

No cancellation of backup process will not affect next backup.